# Action of $PGL_2$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I am studying Fulton and Harris' book and in the chapter "Geometric Plethysm" they talk about how the action of $PGL_2$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ fixes the rational normal curve $C$ of degree $n$. But I have an extremely basic confusion, namely what is said action of $PGL_2$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$? I don't see any obvious candidates.

I guess that if this is resolved I will be able to see why it fixes $C$. I tried to work backwards from the fact that it fixes $C$ to find the action but no luck there.

Comment: There is an obvious degree-$(n+1)$ irrep of $GL_2(k)$ (assuming $k=\bar{k}$, which I think F&H assume the case $k=\mathbb{C}$?), namely, $n$-fold symmetric product of the defining representation, and projectivise to get $PGL_2(k)$ acting on $\mathbb{P}^n_k$.

Comment: @user10354138 this looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the natural action of $GL_2$ on $\Bbb P^1$ by coordinate transformations. This induces an action on the global sections of any sheaf on $\Bbb P^1$. In particular, we get an induced action on $\Gamma(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}(n))=k[x_0,x_1]_n$, a vector space of dimension $n+1$. This action is $k$-linear, so it descends to an action of $PGL_2$ on the projectivization of this vector space, or $\Bbb P^n$. This is the action that's meant.